# How to obtain the same result of the same system if I write the system in different ways (NDSolve)?

Tags: differential-equations

I did program where I solved a system when I organized in matrix form, this is the code

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234]

Nmax = 5; (*Number of sites*)

tini = 0; (*initial time*)

tmax = 200; (*maximal time*)

\[Sigma]2 = 0; (*Variance*)

n0 = 5; (*initial condition*)

ra = 1; (*coupling range*)

\[Psi]ini = Table[KroneckerDelta[n0 - i], {i, 1, Nmax}];

RR = RandomReal[{-Sqrt[3*\[Sigma]2], Sqrt[3*\[Sigma]2]}, Nmax];

Z = Table[
    Sum[KroneckerDelta[i - j + k], {k, 1, ra}] + 
     Sum[KroneckerDelta[i - j - k], {k, 1, ra}], {i, 1, Nmax}, {j, 1, 
     Nmax}] + DiagonalMatrix[RR];

Clear[\[Psi]]

usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[\[Psi][t], t] == 
    Z.\[Psi][t], \[Psi][0] == \[Psi]ini}, \[Psi], {t, tini, tmax}]

Plot[usol[t], {t, tini, tmax}]
```

Now, I´m trying to solve the same system but writing the equations

```
Clear["Global`*"]

tini = 0;

tmax = 200;

usol = NDSolveValue[{I x1'[t] == x2[t], I x2'[t] == x1[t] + x3[t], 
    I x3'[t] == x2[t] + x4[t], I x4'[t] == x3[t] + x5[t], 
    I x5'[t] == x4[t], x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 0, x4[0] == 0,
     x5[0] == 1}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, {t, tini, tmax}];

Plot[usol[t], {t, tini, tmax}]
```

Why the second code doesn´t give me the same result if I write the same system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `usol` is a five-dimensional `InterpolatingFunction`:
[image]

In the second case, `usol` is a list of five `InterpolatingFunctions`:
[image]

You can plot them using `Through`:

```
Plot[Through[usol[t]], {t, tini, tmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris K, you solved my doubt